# OAuth2 not for authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid

What is the main reason OAuth2 is not enough for authentication?

I can see that if userA logs into evil.com, then owner of evil.com can submit userA's access_token to good.com (or any other login with fb website) and pretend to be userA.

But if good.com checks if access token was intended for it, then I don't see any possibility of attacks..

I can't see the fuss about this. For example facebook gives me the App id when I get the access_token details. How is an attack possible if I am checking this?

Is it not a security vulnerability but lack of standards? like which scope or which field email is in etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The access token you receive just represents an authorization issued to the client. It just allows the client to access on protected resources, but it does not give you any information about the resource owner.

In your example, evil.com can get those resources that own the userA, but cannot know who userA is.

Please loook at [this excellent video](https://youtu.be/BdKmZ7mPNns?t=4m40s) about OAuth2 and the Authorization/Authentication terms. It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The access token does give you information (possibly) information about the Resource Owner but it does not give you information about whether the Resource Owner is present and/or how he/she authenticated even if you'd be able to identify whether the token was meant for you in some undefined non-standard way (the latter being another advantage of OpenID Connect over OAuth 2.0 as the OP already mentions).